# Laravel - Eloquent Relationship not working

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent, relational-database

I have two models with One-to-Many relationship. I want to display data with relationship in blade.

**Shop Table**

`id | name | url
 1  |  NY | ny |
 2  | CA  | ca |`

**Products Table**

`id | shop_id | slug
 1  |    1    | ca
 2  |    2    | wa`

**Shop.php**

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Product::class, 'shop_id');
}
```

**Product Model**

```
 public function shops()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Shop::class, 'id');
}
```

**Controller.php**

```
public function category($slug)
{

    $shop = Shop::where('url', $slug)->firstorfail();
    $products = Product::with(['shops'])->where(['shop_id' => $shop->id)->get();
    $url = Shop::where('id', $products->shop_id)->pluck('url');
}
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('/{url}/{slug}', 'Controller@category')->name('view')->where('slug', '[\w\d\-]+(.*)');
```

**View**

```
<a href="{{ route('view', [$url, $products->slug]) }}"
```

It returns **Property [shop_id] does not exist on this collection instance.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Try this:  
  public function products(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product','shop_id','id');
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the shops relationship you just do

```
products = Product::where('shop_id',$shop->id)->get();
```

in fact you function doesn't return a value, what is it used for?

Comment: Not worked. I used this to get only **``shop urls``** which match the ``shop_id`` from products table with ``id`` in Shop table

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly ?

Comment: I want to pre-fix the **``shop urls``** to every ``product slugs``, which matches the respected shop with relationship. Eg. For product no. 1, I want to display its url as domain.com/ny/ca, for product 2: domain.com/ca/wa

Comment: actually for code sake it's better to have relation defined

Answer (score 0):

You specified the wrong column:

```
public function shops()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Shop::class, 'shop_id');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here:`<a href="{{ route('view', [$url, $products->slug]) }}"`

```
$products - this is collection. You need to do $products[0]->slug
```

or

```
@foreach($products as $product)
<a href="{{ route('view', [$url, $product->slug]) }}"
@endforeach
```